# wix - program still listed in programs & features after removing it via upgrade tag

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create an installer that removes an old version of a program that has a different upgrade code (let's consider it just a different program).
According to some research, that should be possible using an upgrade tag :

```
<Upgrade Id="{5B68E7A8-FD95-470D-AD0D-D32B9625A313}">
  <UpgradeVersion Property="OLDPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="no"   Minimum="0.0.0" />
</Upgrade>
```

Problems is that it works almost (so removes files and most registry entries) but still leaves an entry for it in programs & features.

To remove that as well, I wrote a little tool that calls the original setup which can be found found via the uninstall string in the registry. That tool is then asynchronously called via a custom action.

However, this is kind of a kludge and I would rather this happened in one go.

Any suggestions to make this work would be welcome.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can only do guesswork.

Comment: You should do a verbose log of the upgrade. The older Programs&Features entry should be removed (unless it's a Burn entry and not a Windows Installer one).

Comment: The older program was also installed via a Wix created installer - I guess that qualifies as a 'Burn' entry ? (sorry, I don't have much Wix experience)
If so, how to remove it ?

Comment: @Adrie: I'm guessing because there is still not enough information. Get a full verbose log of the upgrade.

Comment: @PhilDW 
Thanks - I generated a log file. Extreeeemely verbose..
It does have entries about the old version getting removed (files) but I don't see any errors which indicate problems removing the old version from list of installed programs - and so the old version stays still listed.
I don't want to include that file here, but can send it to you if you want.

Comment: Can't you find a web hosting location?

Comment: sure, can I PM the address to you ?